# Jenkins archive path with docker environment

Tags: docker, jenkins, artifact

We use Jenkins with the 'copyArtifact-Plugin' to archive files from a build job. Now we moved our Jenkins Master into a docker container.

**This archive features works very well:**

- archive artifacts
- copy artifacts from other projekts

**This archive features doesn't work:**

- The link 'artifacts of the last succesful builds' from the projekt
  website to show and download the archive in browser produces a
  jenkins devil with this exception:

> ```
> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The parent does not exist
>   at hudson.FilePath$IsDescendant.invoke(FilePath.java:3315)
>   at hudson.FilePath$IsDescendant.invoke(FilePath.java:3295)
> ```

Does anybody knows why the link from the project site only works wenn the archive path is directly in the docker container? When the archive path ist outside the docker container and mapped inside the container you can't get the archive. The build results are also outside the container but the master can read this informations.